# Why does this function return different values?

Tags: c++, function, complex-numbers, complextype

I have written a function in C++ to calculate a Spherical Harmonic (using the gcc complex library):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

double plegendre( int, int, double );

complex<double> SphericalHarmonicY( int l, int m, double theta, double phi )
{
   int m_abs;
   double im, re, plm;
   complex<double> output;

   m_abs = fabs(m);

   plm = plegendre( l, m_abs, cos( theta ) );

   re = plm * cos( m * phi );
   im = plm * sin( m * phi );

   if ( m < 0 )
   {
     re = - re;
     im = - im;
   }

   output = complex<double>( re, im );

   cout << " {" << l << "," << m << "}\t" << "theta = " << theta << " phi = " << phi << 
   " SH = " << output << endl;

   return output;
}
```

If I call this function through a simple "main()" it works and gives the correct values.

However, when called through the subroutine below, it only gives the correct real part for values of m that are even and correct imaginary part for values of m that are odd. Can anyone explain this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include "MyHeader.h"

void SphericalHarmCalc( int* P, double* theta, double* phi, SpherHarm** &SHout )
{
   int l, m, i{0};
   double theta_, phi_;

   theta_ = *theta;
   phi_   = *phi;

   SHout = new SpherHarm*[(*P)+1];

   for ( i = 0; i <= (*P); i++ )
   {    
      SHout[i] = new SpherHarm[(2*i)+1];
   }

   for ( l = 0; l <= (*P); l++)
   {
      i = 0;
      for ( m = -l; m <= l; m++ )
      {
         SHout[l][i].lm[0] = l;
         SHout[l][i].lm[1] = m;

         SHout[l][i].val = SphericalHarmonicY( l, m, theta_, phi_ );
         i++;
      }
      cout << endl << endl;
   }
}
```

This has been confusing me for some time.

(also I do use `delete[]` to free the heap later - outside this subroutine).

The class SpherHarm is defined in the MyHeader.h:

```
class SpherHarm
{
   public:
     int* lm = new int[2];
     complex<double> val;
};
```

And I am using the g++ compiler (version 4.8.2) with flags:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you tag a C++ question as [tag:c]? Genuinely curious.

Comment: 1) Would be useful to see the calling code for `SphericalHarmCalc()`.  2) Minor: `m_abs = fabs(m);` --> `m_abs = abs(m);`  (FP math not needed for `int`.

Comment: Can you provide an minimal working example of both cases?